# Search input doesn't appear on the network leaderboard

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021, winterbash-leaderboard

There is a search functionality on the Winter Bash leaderboard:

[image: the search input]

However, it doesn't appear to work on the [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network):

[image: no search input on the network-wide leaderboard]

There's also an error in the console - it seems the [typewatch](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) plugin hasn't loaded:

[image: console error]